# sed : printing lines between two words only when one of the line matches a third word or any pattern

Tags: linux, sed, awk

i know sed prints lines between words FOO and BAR from test.txt using the following command

```
  sed -n '/FOO/,/BAR/p' test.txt
```

but how do i make sed print the lines between FOO and BAR only when one of the lines has a matching pattern

For example, the file text.txt has the following lines :

```
Error- Undefined port
line1
line2
Undefined port in ALU1 
line3

Error- Undefined port
line4
line5
Undefined port in LSU 
line6

Error- Undefined port
line7
line8
Undefined port in FGU 
line9 

Error- Undefined port
line10
line11
Undefined port in ALU2 
line12
```

i want to print out lines between the two successive occurrences of the 
 word "Error" only when one of the lines contain the word "ALU".

so i just want to print out the following Error messages :

```
Error- Undefined port
line1
line2
Undefined port in ALU1 
line3

Error- Undefined port
line10
line11
Undefined port in ALU2 
line12
```

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, you need branching in the sed script and hold buffer.

The script uses two buffers: pattern buffer (it is the buffer where sed stores currently processed line and which is used for the pattern matching tests) and the hold buffer (buffer intented for storing previous lines). The thought is to store all lines from the last `/Error/` pattern match and check the `/ALU/` occurence in the time of next `/Error/` match or the end of stream.

```
sed -n '
# if /Error/ pattern occured, jump to /ALU/ check
/Error/ b alu_check
# else append current line to the hold buffer
H
# if the current line is the last one, jump to /ALU/ check
$ b alu_check
# otherwise jump to end of script (= finish processing of this line)
b
# alu_check:
:alu_check
# exchange current pattern buffer with hols buffer context
x
# print previous record if /ALU/ occured
/ALU/ p
'
```

`x` order exchanges the pattern buffer context (current line) with hold buffer context (what is remembered from the last time) - notice that it stores current line with /Error/ pattern to the hold buffer for the next time

`H` appends current line context to the hold buffer

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else, just use awk. Learning how to do stuff like this in sed is a good mental exercise but not really useful since the slightest change in requirements usually means a total re-write of the code.

Answer (score 2):

An awk variant:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS="\n"}/^Error.+ALU/' file
```

`RS` (Record Separator) is forced on the blank lines

`FS` (Field Separator) on single line return

`ORS` (Output Record Separator) is set on blank line for the output (remove this if you don't need it)

`/^Error.+ALU/` If the record (the block of text) starts with `Error` and contains `ALU` --> print the block.

Comment: No need to set FS, no need for ^Error.+ in the RE, and setting RS to multiple characters makes the script unnecessarily gawk-specific.

Comment: I checked `mawk` man page, «Since mawk interprets RS as a regular
expression, multi-line records are easy. Setting RS = "\n\n+", makes
one or more blank lines separate records.». So that idiom is unnecessarily mawk-specific too.

Answer (score 2):

awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '/ALU/' file

Comment: You wrote `-v RS= -v ORS...`. Have I to understand that the record separator is set to nil?  and, if I am correct, why a nil RS implies separating records on blank lines? tia,

Answer (score 0):

Legacy:

```
awk '{FS="\n";RS=""} $0 ~ /ALU/ {print $0"\n"}' file
```

Comment: No need to set FS, no need for $0 ~ in the condition, you could set ORS="\n\n" instead of manually printing with an extra "\n", and setting of RS  etc. should be done in the BEGIN block.