# Regex with sed, search across multiple lines

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I'd like to concatenate a few lines, perform a regex match on them and print them.
I tried to do that with sed.

Namely, I used:

```
cat add | sed -rn '/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/,/LAST_LINE_REGEX/s/SOME_REGEX/&/p'
```

It prints only the lines that match SOME_REGEX while I expect it to concatenate the lines from the range between FIRST_LINE and LAST_LINE and print the concatenation if it matches SOME_REGEX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `'/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/,/LAST_LINE_REGEX/'` each line is still processed separately, to concatenate lines you need to use the hold space or the `N` command to append the next line to the pattern space.  Here is one option:

```
cat add | sed -rn '/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/{:a;N;/LAST_LINE_REGEX/{/SOME_REGEX/p;d};ba}'
```

Commented version:

```
cat add | sed -rn '/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/ {  # if line matches /FIRST_LINE_REGEX/
  :a                                       # create label a
  N                                        # read next line into pattern space
  /LAST_LINE_REGEX/ {                      # if line matches /LAST_LINE_REGEX/
    /SOME_REGEX/p                            # print if line matches /SOME_REGEX/
    d                                        # return to start
  }
  ba                                       # return to label a
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n '/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/,/LAST_LINE_REGEX/p' add | sed -n '/FIRST_LINE_REGEX/ b check; H; $ b check; b; :check; x; /SOME_REGEX/p'`

The motivation of the second pipe part comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6287105/992834

Edit: Amended for when SOME_REGEX is in between.

Comment: This would still only print lines that contain `SOME_REGEX`, I think the OP wants to print the entire blocks that start with `FIRST_LINE_REGEX`, end with `LAST_LINE_REGEX`, and contain `SOME_REGEX`.

Comment: The problem is the first section passes the lines as lines and they are still processed separately. I'd like the second section to print all content between FIRST_LINE and SECOND_LINE if the content matches SOME_REGEX

Comment: Emphasis on the "if it matches SOME_REGEX." duly noted

Comment: @Gospo another alternative.  Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286486/sed-printing-lines-between-two-words-only-when-one-of-the-line-matches-a-third but you have a 'start' and 'end' tag instead of just a 'start' tag