# sed find and replace between two tags with multi line

Tags: linux, sed

I want to find and replace a pattern where

```
text="
hold1
hold2 
<file option1='one'>
some text
some text 
...
... more data
</file>
this1
that1
"

pattern="<file.*</file>"

replacewith="<sometext>
value1
</sometext>"

output text="
hold1
hold2
<sometext> 
value1
</sometext>
this1
that1
"
```

P.S. These questions on Stackoverflow do not help.
[sed : printing lines between two words only when one of the line matches a third word or any pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286486/sed-printing-lines-between-two-words-only-when-one-of-the-line-matches-a-third/6287105#)

[Regex with sed, search across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045927/unix-regex-with-sed-search-across-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sed` you can try something like:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's#<file.*</file>#<sometext>\nvalue1\n</sometext>#' file
```

My `sed` is a little rusty but what we are doing here is using `:a;N;$!ba` we effectively create one long line in pattern space so that we can apply the second expression which does your substitution.

This will probably need `GNU sed`

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
hold1
hold2
<file option1='one'>
some text
some text
more data
</file>
this1
that1
```

```
$ sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's#<file.*</file>#<sometext>\nvalue1\n</sometext>#' file
hold1
hold2
<sometext>
value1
</sometext>
this1
that1
```

Comment: other commands can also be used like awk there but sed is easy to implement in some cases. Thanks.